# Overriding a function

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

```
template<typename T>
class ITF{
public:
    virtual  T& EQUAL(const T& K) = 0;
};

class S : public virtual ITF<S> {

private:
    char *Name;
    int k;
    float IQ;

public:
    S &operator=(const S &K);

    S &EQUAL(const S &K) override;
};

S& S::EQUAL(const S &K){

    if(this != &K)
    {
        if(this -> Name != nullptr)
        {
            delete[] Name;
            (*this).Name = nullptr;
        }

        this -> Name = new char[strlen(K.Name) + 1];
        strcpy(Name, K.Name);

        k = K.k;
        IQ = K.IQ;
    }

    return *this;
}
S& S::operator = (const S& K){
    return (*this).EQUAL(K);
}


class D : public virtual  S{

private:
    bool Ra;

public:

    D &operator=(const D &M);

    D& EQUAL(const D& M) override{
        S::EQUAL(M);
        Ra = M.Ra;
        return *this;
    }

};

D& D::operator = (const D& M){
    return (*this).EQUAL(M);
}
```

So the thing is that this code would work if I were to remove the keyword "override" from  `D& EQUAL(const D& M) override`. But I don't understand why it doesn't work with it. In Clion under the word "override" appears that red line and says this
"Non-virtual member function marked 'override' hides virtual member function hidden overloaded virtual function 'S::EQUAL' declared here: type mismatch at 1st parameter ('const S &' vs 'const D &')". I don't get it why it confuses a const S& with a const D&. Could someone explain?

Comment: Unrelated to your problems, but `(*this).EQUAL(K)` would be shorter to write with `this->EQUAL(K)`. Or just plain `EQUAL(K)`. And a better name would be `assign` as that's what it does. The term "equal" is more related to comparison.

Comment: `D::EQUAL` only accepts a `const D&` as its argument. However, `ITF<S>::EQUAL`, the method it's overriding, requires it to accept any `const S&` as its argument. Since there are `S`s that are not `D`s, the compiler is correct to tell you that `D::EQUAL` is not overriding anything.

Comment: As for your problem, `D& EQUAL(const D& M)` just isn't the same as `S &EQUAL(const S &K)`. So the `D::EQUAL` function just can't override the base function, only *shadow* it.

Comment: So I understand what you say. So if I were to rewrite the class D declaration this way: "class D : public virtual  S, public virtual ITF<D>" it will work as well. I assume this is the case because now I directly override the function EQUAL from ITF. Is this assumption right? Is this good solution?

Comment: That is correct in the sense that your signature for `D::EQUAL` would override `ITF<D>::EQUAL`. Whether that's a "good solution" isn't really answerable, because we don't have any idea what the heck `ITF` or `S` or `D` or `EQUAL` are supposed to be or be used for, but I suspect that you need to go back and look at your design and requirements and figure out what you actually want rather than just add additional template contortions until it compiles.

Comment: More likely than not, you will get a mess on your hands if you do multiple inheritance. I suspect you want to have a `ITF*` pointing to both `S` and `D`, which wouldn't work.

Comment: Well ITF is an interface and S is a base class for D. I am learning OOP so I don't have requirements but what I am trying to do is to overloading the "=" operator and minimizing the written code. So I don't know if the way I am doing it is a good way of doing it. I would like to know if there is a common way of doing such a thing.

Comment: Why does `EQUAL` need to be polymorphic?  What exactly are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: I don't try to achieve anything big. Making EQUAL polymorphic is what I want to do for learning purposes and I want to know if this is how it should be done, if there is a better way, things like this.

Comment: OK, put it this way.  Given a `D`, how do you want to assign to it (a) from another `D`, and (b) from an `S`?  Now do you see what I mean?

Comment: By overloading the assign operator. I think you want to say that I am
unnecessarily complicating it by using abstract classes and pure virtual functions.

Comment: You nailed it.  Wrote up an answer which I thought might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question has gone rather quiet, I thought I'd try and answer it, even though the problem that the OP wants to solve is still rather vague.

It seems to me, the question is how to implement `operator=` with minimum code duplication for classes `S` and `D`.  So, on that assumption, I would do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template<typename T>
class ITF
{
};

class S : public virtual ITF <S>
{
private:
    char *Name = nullptr;
    int k = 0;
    float IQ = 0;

public:
    S &operator= (const S &K);
};

S& S::operator = (const S &K)
{
    if (this != &K)
    {
        delete [] Name;
        Name = nullptr;

        if (K.Name)
        {
            Name = new char [strlen (K.Name) + 1];
            strcpy (Name, K.Name);
        }
            
        k = K.k;
        IQ = K.IQ;
    }

    return *this;
}

class D : public virtual  S
{
private:
    bool Ra;

public:
    D &operator= (const D &M);
    D& operator= (const S &M);
};

D& D::operator= (const D &M)
{
    if (this != &M)
    {
        S::operator= (M);
        Ra = M.Ra;
    }
    return *this;
}

D& D::operator= (const S &M)
{
    S::operator= (M);
    return *this;
}

int main ()
{
    S s1;
    S s2;
    D d1;
    D d2;

    d1 = d2;
    s1 = s2;
    d1 = s2;
}
```

Notes:

- When copying a `D`, one can invoke `S::operator=` explicitly (I think this is the key piece that the OP was missing).
- The `EQUAL` function that was leading us astray is therefore no longer needed.
- There is no polymorphism involved; just good old-fashioned function overloading.

Having said all of which, this might not scale well (but then you would question the design of the class hierarchy, perhaps).

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CQOgYLmixAclOqdT)